# Configuração virtual hosts no vagrant homestead/laravel

Tags: laravel, vagrant

Estou iniciando em **Laravel** e gostaria de organizar meu ambiente de desenvolvimento usando alguns "**hosts**" para os meus projetos. Criei o primeiro projeto em **laravel** e depois de sofrer um pouco com a sua instalação, ele funcionou que foi uma beleza. Em seguida iniciei um novo projeto, configurei o **homestead.yaml** e o **hosts** do meu sistema, mas quando tento acessar pelo navegador ele ainda aponta para o primeiro projeto. Tentei parar o server do **artisan** mas continuou com o problema, pesquisei na internet e as soluções que achei não funcionaram . Uso o **ubuntu 16.04** e o **laravel 5.2** com o **homestaed** (**vagrant/virtualbox**). Abaixo transcrevo parte dos arquivos **hosts** e **Homestead.ymal** para que possam ter uma ideia de como foram configurados. Peço ajuda aos amigos para tentar resolver esse problema. Obrigado.

```
[hosts]
# vagrant hosts
192.168.10.10 homestead.app
192.168.10.10 api.app
[homestead.yaml]
ip: "192.168.10.10"
folders:
- map: /home/<user>/Dropbox/Projetos/Laravel-PHP/Projetos
to: /home/vagrant/Code
sites:
- map: homestead.app
to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public
- map: api.app
to: /home/vagrant/Code/ApiTeste/public
```

Comment: Veja a orientação do site do Laravel:
http://laravel.artesaos.org/docs/5.1/homestead#adding-additional-sites

Answer (score -1):

Cara, você precisar dar o comando `vagrant init` dentro da pasta do seu projeto. Feito isso um arquivo chamado `vagrantfile` será gerado. Você precisa abrir esse arquivo e setar a box do homestead nele. Acredito que você já tenha feito isso com o primeiro projeto.

Answer (score -1):

Tens de fazer **provision** novamente a box, se a box já está iniciada, deves usar o comando `vagrant reload --provision` a partir da linha de comandos no host, ele vai ler novamente o Homestead.yaml e configurar o nginx correctamente.

Reiniciar **não** é suficiente, pois a box já está provisioned e esse passo é ignorado durante o arranque.

Se a máquina está parada podes também usar a flag `provision` no arranque para as novas configuracoes serem lidas `vagrant up --provision`.

Provavelmente este problema já está resolvido, mas fica aqui a resposta caso alguém tenha um problema similar no futuro.

Curioso que essa pergunta com quase 2 anos, chegou a primeira página quando estou a tentar configurar uma box usando `laravel/homestead` para correr Magento2.

Comment: Você já tentou `vagrant reload`?